# GSSAPI: The Security Context Loop

Tags: java, kerberos, spnego, gssapi

The Oracle GSSAPI Java examples, and various SPNEGO / GSSAPI IETF RFCs indicate that both the GSS initiator (client) and acceptor (server) should have a loop to establish a security context, and that the client may need to make multiple passes with GSS tokens before the security context is established.

- Oracle GSSAPI example:
  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/BasicClientServer.html
- Structure of the Generic Security Service (GSS) Negotiation Loop:
  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7546
- SPNEGO-based Kerberos and NTLM HTTP Authentication in Microsoft Windows:
  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4559

For instance RFC4559 gives this example:

**Pass 1:** Fails because request does not have a token:

C: GET dir/index.html

S: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

S: WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate

**Pass 2:** Fails, but request has a token

C: GET dir/index.html

C: Authorization: Negotiate a87421000492aa874209af8bc028

S: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

S: WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate 749efa7b23409c20b92356

**Pass 3:** Succeeds

C: GET dir/index.html

C: Authorization: Negotiate 89a8742aa8729a8b028

S: HTTP/1.1 200 Success

S: WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate ade0234568a4209af8bc0280289eca

Here the security context is established and thus the request is authenticated on the third pass. i.e. on the second pass from the client (C) to server (S) with a token.

**Question 1:**
Why might multiple passes from initiator to acceptor with tokens be required before the security context is successfully established?
Why might pass 2 above fail, but pass 3 succeed?
Does something change on either the initiator or the acceptor between these 2 passes?

**Question 2:**
My instinct is that both the initiator and acceptor loops should have protection against endless looping.
For instance the initiator could abort if the context is not established by x attempts.
Are there any rules-of-thumb / metrics on the number of passes that might reasonably be expected to establish the security context?
e.g. if the security context has not been established by the 5th pass --> abort.

**Question 3:**
In the Oracle GSSAPI examples the client and server communicate over sockets.
The server builds a GSSContext object which is dedicated to a single client, is kept until the server closes, and is thus available for multiple passes to establish the security context.

But how might this work for a Http RESTful WebServer with multiple clients?
My assumption is that:

a) each pass of a request to establish a security context should be made to the same GSSContext object (and not against a new GSSContext instance).

b) the Http server should establish a new GSSContext instance for each new client request.
(i.e. a GSSContext object should not be shared / reused across multiple clients / requests).

If my assumptions are correct the server must distinguish between:

i) a following pass for an existing request for which the security context has not yet been established. --> an existing GSSContext object and loop should be used.

ii) the first pass of a totally new request (either from the same or from a different client). --> a new GSSContext object and loop should be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Negotiate` as the example protocol, it's useful to consider how it operates.

1. The server indicates to the client that it can support negotiation.
2. The client agrees and infers what the server might support.
3. The client creates a token based on what it really thinks the server supports (e.g. Kerberos), and then creates a list of other possible token types (e.g. NTLM).
4. The client sends both the token and list to the server.
5. The server either accepts the initial token or decides to pick something else from the list.
6. The server indicates to the client that it wants something else.
7. The client then sends another token of the preferred type.
8. The server accepts or declines and responds to the client appropriately.

This requires up to three roundtrips and may fail or complete after one. Other protocols may choose to do whatever they want.

You will probably want to track the number of roundtrips and kill it after a arbitrarily high number. The resources required aren't that high, but under load it can exhaust the system.

Comment: Clear and succinct: what had escaped me was that the GSS data sent by the client in the Negotiate string contains one token and a list of alternatives, and that a subsequent pass (if required) should contain a token of a different type until one is accepted by the server (or all are rejected). This explains why my client and server (both fully under my control) always succeed with the first token sent by the client.

Comment: Does that mean that as long as the client chooses a mechanism supported by the server initially (say, Kerberos), you're guaranteed that only a single roundtrip will be required? (that is, client sends an initial token to the server, server responds with another token, and auth is complete once the client has consumed that token)?

Or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: No, that's not guaranteed. The guarantee is both parties will indicate to each other whether each is satisfied. If party A isn't satisfied then party B must either continue the negotiation, or fail. In the Kerberos case the server will happily respond with an error code that triggers the client to try again for reasons and you need to honor that (or fail).

Comment: And I suppose to be more precise: _SPNego_ will technically only allow two token exchanges. The first initial token and then the second "I didn't like that, gimme the next one" token. The protocol shuts down if the second isn't accepted.